# You cannot move or copy a sheet that contains a table

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, office365

I am trying to copy a sheet to another workbook. It has a slicer that is connected to the table.I want to move both Table and slicer. I get an error saying "You cannot move or copy a sheet that contains a table". What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

To move or copy a sheet that contains a table, you need to convert the table to a range. To do this, follow these steps:

1. Select any cell in the table.
2. On the Ribbon, go to the "Table Tools" tab and click on "Design".
3. In the "Tools" group, click on "Convert to Range".
4. Save the workbook.
5. Now you can move or copy the sheet to another workbook.

After you have moved or copied the sheet, you can convert the range back to a table by selecting the data range and pressing `Ctrl+T`.

Comment: It is not that simple. Usually, tables are tied with slices, and if you convert them to a range, you will lose them along with the meaningful formulas, and that will not come back!